# How to upload file in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to upload an image to a server using POST and then expect a json string which I need to process in my NativeScript app.

I have tried using fetch but it require Blob/File web API that is not supported by NativeScript.

I have tried also using nativescript-background-http but it does not allow me to process the response (json string). Its oncomplete() event only pass me the task object which does not contain the response string.

I am thinking of extending the nativescript-background-http but it seems an overkill considering the basic nature of my requirement.

> Question: How can I upload file in nativescript and process the
>   response string as json?

I am new to nativescript so my apology if some of my observation above is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Nativescript provides a [`http` API](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/http/README) which you want to use, and upload the file as [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Something like this:

```
http.request({
    url: "https://example.com",
    method: "POST",
    FormData: YOUR-FORM-DATA-HERE
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.content.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: Hi Emil. I have tried that. However the FormData set() expect a File or Blob API Web API class to properly upload a file. Pasing File class from {N} filesystem module only result in it being treated as String (ie. another field-value pair instead of a File form type).

Comment: Hey Yoga. Any update on this? Have you managed to upload a file using NativeScript?

Comment: Same question as commenter above.